# Efficiently find if user is present in many-to-many relationship in Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

Users can follow Games, and Games have followers. This is a simple many-to-many association.

When rendering a list of Games, I need to determine if the authenticated user is following the game in that specific iteration. Like so:

```
$games = App\Game::with('users')->all();

foreach($games as $game) {
    echo $game->title;
    echo $game->is_auth_user_following; // bool
}
```

So in my Game model I have this accessor:

```
// App\Game
public function getIsAuthUserFollowingAttribute()
{
    if (!Auth::id()) {
        return false;
    }

    return $this->users()->where('users.id', Auth::id())->exists();
}
```

This works fine, however, when analyzing the queries executed by Eloquent, I see it running a separate query for each Game in the loop. If the loop had 50 games, then I get 50 queries that look like this:

```
select exists(select * from `users`
                       inner join `game_user`
                           on `users`.`id` = `game_user`.`user_id`
                       where `game_user`.`game_id` = ?
                         and `users`.`id` = ?
                         and `users`.`deleted_at` is null) as `exists`
--- this 50 times...
```

**Question:** is there any way to optimize this in Eloquent in order to reduce the number of queries against the pivot table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using this code

```
$games = App\Game::with('users')->all();
```

Then you can change your accessor this way. It will not do any query

```
public function getIsAuthUserFollowingAttribute()
{
    if (!Auth::id()) {
        return false;
    }

    return $this->users->where('id', Auth::id())->isNotEmpty();
}
```

more optimzed code is

```
$games = App\Game::with('users:id')->all();
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! The funny thing with Laravel is how these odd things can make a huge difference. It would have never occurred to me to even try this syntax.